# Does JavaScript interpreter produce value from anything it reads?

Tags: javascript

From [JavaScript eloquent](http://eloquentjavascript.net/01_values.html) book:

> Many **operations** in the language that don’t produce a meaningful value
>   yield undefined simply because **they have to**
>   **yield some value.**

Does the interpreter has to produce a value from anything it reads?
And what are examples of these operations that do not produce a meaningful value?

Comment: The JS language is defined such that all expressions have a value.  But some functions don't return anything.

Comment: @SLaks but in the console functions return *undefined* which is a value.

Comment: That's just what the console does. The console is not part of the language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both statements and expressions have values, but the values of non-expression statements* are not accessible in code. This is meaningful at a specification level, and you can see it in your browser's console, but it doesn't really have any day-to-day utility. Declarations, being outside the step-by-step execution of the code, don't have result values at the specification level (consoles show `undefined` as their result, though).

To see it in action, open your browser console, type this:

```
if (true) "foo"
```

...and press Enter. You'll see `"foo"`. Now try:

```
if (false) "foo"
```

...and press Enter. You'll see `undefined`.

Why? Because the result of [an `if` statement](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-if-statement-runtime-semantics-evaluation) is the result of its body (if the condition is true) or `undefined` (if the condition is false).

Here's what the spec link above says about `if (condition) statement`:

> Runtime Semantics: Evaluation
>
> *IfStatement*: `if (`*Expression*`)` *Statement*
>
> 1. Let *exprRef* be the result of evaluating *Expression*.
> 2. Let *exprValue* be ToBoolean(? GetValue(*exprRef*)).
> 3. If *exprValue* is **false**, then
>
>    1. Return NormalCompletion(**undefined**).
>
>    Else
>
>    1. Let *stmtCompletion* be the result of evaluating *Statement*.
> 4. Return Completion(UpdateEmpty(*stmtCompletion*, **undefined**)).

...where *Completion(...)* creates a [completion record](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-completion-record-specification-type); the first argument is the *value* of the completion.

Here's another one to try in your console:

```
var n = 4; while (n--) { "body " + n; }
```

The result is `"body 0"` because the value of a `while` statement is the value of the *last* execution of its body (or `undefined` if it never executed the body).

---

* *"non-expression statements"* - JavaScript allows any expression to be a statement if it appears where a statement is expected (this is how function calls work as statements, for instance). Which is why my `"foo"` in `if (true) "foo"` works; it's an *expression statement* where the expression is a string literal.